# zsh autocompletion for a fresh executable in PATH

Tags: zsh

After copying a new executable to PATH, bash autocompletion for that command kicks in no problem, but zsh needs to be restarted.

How do I nudge zsh autocompletion to pick it up without restarting the shell?
Can it pick it up automatically?

Comment: Have you tried `rehash`?

Comment: Answer added :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### How do I nudge zsh autocompletion to pick it up

Use `rehash`:

- `rehash` re-computes the internal hash table of the contents of directories listed in the path environment variable to account for new commands added.

> **Persistent rehash**
>
> Typically, compinit will not automatically find new executables in the
>   `$PATH`. For example, after you install a new package, the files in
>   `/usr/bin` would not be immediately or automatically included in the
>   completion. Thus, to have these new exectuables included, one would
>   run:
>
> ```
> $ rehash
> ```
>
> This 'rehash' can be set to happen automatically. Simply include the
>   following in your zshrc:
>
> ```
> ~/.zshrc
> zstyle ':completion:*' rehash true
> ```

Source [zsh - Persistent rehash](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Persistent_rehash)