# Zsh not picking up new executable in PATH

Tags: zsh

So, I see https://superuser.com/a/1089956/954104 and have tried the guidance there.

```
% which ndjsonMover.js
/Users/marvin/git/internal/tools/scripts/./js/ndjsonMover.js
% ls -l /Users/marvin/git/internal/tools/scripts/./js/ndjsonMover.js
-rwxr-xr-x  1 marvin  staff  6816 May  3 10:09 /Users/marvin/git/internal/tools/scripts/./js/ndjsonMover.js
% ndj <tab... NOTHING>
% rehash
% ndj <tab... NOTHING>
% ndjsonMover.js
< prints usage msg >
% echo $PATH
/Users/marvin/git/in<..snip..> 6.3/bin:/Users/marvin/git/internal/tools/scripts/./py3:/Users/marvin/git/internal/tools/scripts/./js
```

Even starting a new zsh subshell isn't completing scripts in my scripts dir.

Answer (score 0):

So, this seems to be an artifact of my PATH having `./` in the PATH.  Although zsh correctly finds the executables, the completion magic doesn't.  Fixing the paths in PATH seems to fix the issue.  I'll upvote someone else's answer if they have some interesting info about this (like existing bug report or some zsh setting I can use to do completions when the PATH has "/./" in it.

Comment: The answer was given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1089949/zsh-autocompletion-for-a-fresh-executable-in-path). Run `rehash` to update manually, or put `zstyle ':completion:*' rehash true` in `~/.zshrc` to rehash automatically.

Comment: @GiancarloSportelli - in the example above, I explicitly run rehash.  And, though it has been a while, I don't think the script in question was new.  As I said, I think it had something to do with `/./` in some part of my PATH